# Trigger for Killed Sessions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use a trigger when a session is killed / ended. Is it possible?

My program is connecting a table and update "online" field when it is online. If my program crashed or my mssql connection killed, i want to update "online" field...

For example: When my program is online, it gets spid and update SERVICE_TABLE(spid, online)

```
SEVICE_TABLE
------------
id
spid
online
```

when a session is killed / ended, trigger look up SERVICE_TABLE. Is killed spid in SERVICE_TABLE, update "online" field to false.

Comment: oh :( can you offer any solution?

Comment: if you describe the problem that you think the above design is going to help you solve, we may be able to offer solutions for that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no DDL logout triggers in SQL Server (though there are login ones). Service Broker can be used to process the AUDIT_LOGOUT events though.

[Does this help](http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2008/05/28/auditing-user-log-out-events/)?

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar situation.  I've basically added a "lastseen" to our equivalent of the service table.  A background process in the client updates this field every minute.  (Be sure to create a new database connection every time you update the field.)

If the "lastseen" field is more than 5 minutes in the past, we assume the application has gone the way of the Hindenburg.